# Python Requests : Parsing an Unicode response

Tags: python, http, unicode, python-requests

I am sending a http post request to an api using python requests module that returns a response like below :

```
print resp.text
[{\"status\":\"Success\",\"message\":\"3432ursuyfskfb\"}]

print type(resp.text)
<type 'unicode'>
```

How do I parse this response to a list or dictionary and extract 'status' and 'message' or is there a better way to parse this response ?

Comment: Use `resp.json()`? It's literally in the first example in the docs: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

Comment: print resp.json gives me 
[{"status":"Success","message":"a6ZV0000000FzOQMA0"}] but it is still type <type 'unicode'> . How do I extract the 'status' and 'message' from this ?

Comment: ...yes? That's exactly what you should have expected. That's a list with a dictionary in, the Python equivalent of an object in an array.

Comment: using a=resp.json() and a[0] gives me just '['

Comment: That's not the behaviour I see. Please give a [mcve] that demonstrates that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use resp.json() to do this. See below example

```
>>> r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))
>>> r.status_code
200
>>> r.headers['content-type']
'application/json; charset=utf8'
>>> r.encoding
'utf-8'
>>> r.text
u'{"type":"User"...'
>>> r.json()
{u'private_gists': 419, u'total_private_repos': 77, ...}
```